# tmux: Remap h, j, k, l to j, k, l, ; in choose-tree mode

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to remap hjkl keys in `choose-tree` mode?

I tried the following:

```
unbind -T choose-tree h;
unbind -T choose-tree j;
unbind -T choose-tree k;
unbind -T choose-tree l;

bind -T choose-tree j send-keys -X collapse-selected-item;
bind -T choose-tree k send-keys -X select-next-item;
bind -T choose-tree l send-keys -X select-previous-item;
bind -T choose-tree \; send-keys -X expand-selected-item;
```

But I got an error: `table choose-tree doesn't exist`.

I also tried replace `choose-tree` with `choose-mode` but it also didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide your full configuration by any chance? Are you binding choose tree to your prefix key?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config file.

```
bind-key -T root  j if -F "#{==:#{pane_mode},tree-mode}" "send h" "send j"
bind-key -T root  k if -F "#{==:#{pane_mode},tree-mode}" "send j" "send k"
bind-key -T root  l if -F "#{==:#{pane_mode},tree-mode}" "send k" "send l"
bind-key -T root \; if -F "#{==:#{pane_mode},tree-mode}" "send l" "send \;"
```

Reference: [Is it possible to remap key bindings in `choose-tree` mode? : tmux](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/qwqj39/is_it_possible_to_remap_key_bindings_in/)